# What is the best search method for O(log(m)) time complexity?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, search, time-complexity

I'm searching for the best search algorithm that returns the index of an element in a sorted array in O(log(m)), where m is the number of elements before k.
**Note:** If k isn't in the array, m is the number of elements before the element closest to k.

I thought of a search where each step grows exponentially, not necessarily starting from the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's try to make the range at which `k` could possibly be as small as possible. We will look at elements `a[0], a[1], a[2], ... a[2 ** i], ...` until we find one that is bigger than `k`. Suppose we stopped at index `r`. Then we know for sure that, because the array is sorted, if `k` is in the array, its position `m` is less than `r`. Another fact which is crucial to the time complexity is that `m > i/2`. This is true because at the previous step we looked at `a[r/2]` and it was smaller than `k`.

If we run a simple binary search for the subarray `a[0 ... r]`, we will find `k` in `O(log r)`. The total number of steps to find `r` was `O(log r)`. Since `r > m > r/2` it is true that `log r > log m > log r - 1`. Therefore we can rewrite `O(log r)` as `O(log m)`, which is exactly what we need.

This is my solution in Python 3:

```
def find(a, k):
    if a[0] > k:
        return -1

    r = 1
    while r < len(a):
        if a[r] > k:
            break
        r *= 2

    if r >= len(a):
        if a[-1] < k:
            return -1
        r = len(a) - 1

    l = -1
    while r - l > 1:
        m = (l + r) // 2
        if a[m] < k:
            l = m
        else:
            r = m

    if a[r] == k:
        return r   
    else:
        return -1
```

Comment: I would also like to point out that you should always stop if you find `k` before the algorithm finishes.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [Exponential search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search).

In Exponential search we are jumping indices from 0 in powers of 2 until reaching to an index with value higher than the number we are looking for. i.e. lets say out number is at index 14 we jump until index 16 and stop since the number in the 16'th index is bigger than our number. The time complexity is `O(log m)` since we stop the moment we pass by m by powers of 2.

Than we perform binary search between 0 and the index we stopped at in the previous step. Why? Since now there are no more than 2m numbers between lower and upper bound, so the time complexity of the binary search is `O(log (2m))` which is `O(log m)` and we are done!

A pseudo-code:

```
exponential_search:
 Array A 
 Key k

1. i = 1
2. while A[i - 1] < k and i <= size of A
2.1.  i = i * 2

// Now i is no more than 2 * m

3. perform binary search with k and A between 0 and i
4. return the binary search's result
```